# How to access dropdown text (not value) using Request.Form()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am working on MVC 4.0.

I need to access my dropdown box Text (not value) using Request.Form("ddlId") in my controller code.

and display the selected info on confirmation page of registration.

i.e. lets consider I am having Country dropbox as below.

```
 <select data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="CountryId" name="CountryId" style="width:210px"><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">USA</option><option value="2">UK</option></select>
```

now, in controller when i use,

```
            objWizard.CountryId = Request.Form["CountryId"];
```

I got the value of COuntry dropbox, not the text selected by user.

How can i select text of dropbox using Request.Form(...)????

Or any alternative........

My jquery code is as below.

```
   $.post( '@Url.Action("ConfirmDetails", "Wizard")', $("form").serialize(), function (r)
                    {
                        // inject response in confirmation step
                        //$(".wizard-step:visible")
                        $("#confirmdiv").html(r);
                    });
```

Comment: Actually, you should have all those values stored somewhere on the server, in a database or just in a dictionary. The passed ID should be all you need to find it and present it. After all, you had some way of finding what ID corresponded to what name when you presented the dropdown, didn't you?

Comment: yes, this is the final way to work out. To save somewhere and get it back, however i am looking for the way using Request.Forms[] so it does not require to save in DB or hidden field etc.

Comment: how are you populating the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll assume that you are posting a form and that look likes

```
<form>
<select id="CountryId">
  <option value=1>US</option>
  <option value=2>UK</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

on form submit cancel the default behavior

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//now make a hidden field here and put the text of selected option in that 
var selectedOption = $("#CountryId option:selected").text();
$("<input/>",{type:'hidden',name:'CountryName'}).val(selectedOption).appendTo("form");
// now post the form 
$.post( '@Url.Action("ConfirmDetails", "Wizard")', $("form").serialize(),function (r)
  {
   // inject response in confirmation step
   //$(".wizard-step:visible")
   $("#confirmdiv").html(r);
  });
});
```

in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmDetails()
  {

   var countryName = Request.Form["CountryName"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for this,

```
var selectedLi=$('#CountryId option:selected');

$.post('controller/action',{CountryId :selectedLi.val(),CountryName:selectedLi.text() }, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

And in your action you can get those values like this,

```
 public ActionResult Action(string CountryName,string CountryId )
  {

//...........
  }
```

Comment: if i am not mistaken shouldn't it be like `var selectedLi=$('#CountryId option:selected');`

Comment: also decorate the ActionResult with `[HttpPost]` action filter `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You could emit the value tag as the country name on the server and prevent any need for javascript.

```
<select id="CountryId">
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,
ddlHospitalName.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(Request.Form["ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ddlHospitalName"])).Text;