# access dropdown value generating on runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, runtime

I am using C# asp.net. On button click I am generating a dropdown by using Javascript.

```
<scripttype="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function AddFileUpload() {
//debugger;
var div = document.createElement('DIV');

div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter + '"Type="file"/>' +
'<select id="Droplist' + counter + '" name="droplst"/>' +
'<option value="SCR">Student Count request</option>' +
'<option value="DRO">Documents recieved from others</option>' +
'<option value="TE">total estimates</option>' +
'<option value="PRE">Presentation</option>' +
'<option value="PRI">Pricing</option>' +
'<option value="Quest">Questions to student</option>' +
'<option value="RelvExp">RelevantExperience-Case Studies</option>' +
'<option value="ResReq">Resource requests</option>' +
'<option value="SSP">Student submitted paper</option>' +
'<option value="WIP">WIP</option>' ;
document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
    counter++;
}
</script>
```

I am accessing the dropdown values in page behind like this

```
string val = Request.Form["droplst"];
```

It is working fine,but what I am receiving is option value. Like "SCR" when "Student Count request" is selected. is there any way to access the selected value like "Student Count request" instead of getting the option value?

Please let me know if the question is vague and further clarification is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the values of the options necessary? The easiest change to make would be to remove the values. E.g:

```
<option>Student Count request</option>
```

If you do require the values, then it's a bit more tricky: you have added the dynamic control to the page using JavaScript, so the code behind won't be able to find it easily. You could add an ASP HiddenField control to the page, then when a dropdown is selected, populate that hiddenfield with the text value using JQuery/JavaScript. Then in the code behind you can access the value of the hidden field (which will be the dropdown selected text).

Do you understand? You can read further here which is a duplicate of this question and has already been answered: [How to access dropdown text (not value) using Request.Form()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077910/how-to-access-dropdown-text-not-value-using-request-form)